# Javascript : Not Understanding Looping on Associative Array

Tags: javascript, json, for-in-loop

I have a JSON object (well that is what I thought I had defined) and I am trying to access the values of an array within it. It is looping three times which is correct but the value of `img.iName` is always `undefined`

What have I misunderstood ?

```
<div id="dbgDIV">Debug Div<br></div>
<script>
    // imgs as a JSON array
    var gallery = {"imgs":
                [ // Height and Width to be added
                    {"iName":"File1.jpg", "tName": "File1_th.jpg","cap":"This is a Caption for File1"},
                    {"iName":"File2.jpg", "tName": "File2_th.jpg","cap":"This is a Caption for File2"},
                    {"iName":"File3.jpg", "tName": "File3_th.jpg","cap":"This is a Caption for File3"}
                ],
                "imgCount":"3"
    };
    var dbgDIV = document.getElementById("dbgDIV");
    for (var img in gallery.imgs) {
        dbgDIV.innerHTML = dbgDIV.innerHTML + "img=" + img.iName + "<br>";
        console.log(img.iName);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: use `in`' for object list. for this array just use normal for loop

Comment: You would find it extremely helpful to learn how to use the JavaScript debugger built into all browsers. By single-stepping through your loop, you would immediately discover that `img` in the loop was not a reference to an array element as you expected, but instead was an _array index_, i.e. `0`, `1`, or `2`. Take some time to learn how to use the developer tools and JavaScript debugger; you will find it well worth your while. Here is a [guide to the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Comment: Also note that JavaScript and JSON do not have "associative arrays". They have _objects_, and they have _arrays_. `gallery.imgs` is an array, and as the various answers point out, you should not use a `for`..`in` loop on an array. But the use of `for`..`in` was not the actual problem here! The real reason not to use `for`..`in` on an array is if `Array.prototype` had been extended, those extra properties would show up in your loop. My comment above explains the actual reason for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for...in` loop is the trouble. Just use a traditional `for` loop to index into the array:

```js
var gallery = {
  "imgs": [
    {
      "iName": "File1.jpg",
      "tName": "File1_th.jpg",
      "cap": "This is a Caption for File1"
    },
    {
      "iName": "File2.jpg",
      "tName": "File2_th.jpg",
      "cap": "This is a Caption for File2"
    },
    {
      "iName": "File3.jpg",
      "tName": "File3_th.jpg",
      "cap": "This is a Caption for File3"
    }
  ],
  "imgCount": "3"
};
var dbgDIV = document.getElementById("dbgDIV");
for (var i = 0; i < gallery.imgs.length; i++) {
  var img = gallery.imgs[i];
  console.log(img.iName);
}
```

Comment: I know I am not supposed to - but thank you very much - struggling for well over an hour

Comment: you could also use: for (let img of gallery.imgs) {

Comment: While I agree that `for`..`in` should not be used on an array, that wasn't the cause of OP's problem, nor the reason why the numeric `for` loop fixed it (it didn't). The real fix was the the _other_ change you made, using `gallery.imgs[i]` (where `i` is the loop/array index) instead of `img` in OP's code (where OP did not realize that `img` here was actually an array index too). And as others suggested, either `for`..`of` or `.forEach()` would be a cleaner solution in modern browsers. The numeric `for` loop would be good if you needed to support very old browsers.

Answer (score 2):

you should use a for...of / forEach / for loop instead of the for..in loop you used.

to quickly demonstrate the difference between the for..in and the for..of loop:

```
Object.prototype.objCustom = function() {}; 
Array.prototype.arrCustom = function() {};

let iterable = [3, 5, 7];
iterable.foo = 'hello';

for (let i in iterable) {
  console.log(i); // logs 0, 1, 2, "foo", "arrCustom", "objCustom"
}
for (let i of iterable) {
  console.log(i); // logs 3, 5, 7
}
```

that means that it will not really go through array's elements you wanted but over all enumerable properties of the object. (in javascript all the variables are objects)

I'd suggest you go with something like:

```
gallery.imgs.forEach(img => {
  console.log(img.iName) // "File1.jpg" , "File2.jpg", ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The for...in loops iterates over *keys* , so in an array itll be

```
 0,1,2
```

and these numbers dont have an iName. You may want to iterate over *values* with the for..of loop:

```
for(var img of gallery.imgs)
```